# Как поставить div ы так как на схеме?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Как расположить `div`'ы так

```
Div            Div
    Div Div Div
Div            Div
```

Comment: Объясните ещё раз, сейчас ничего не понятно

Comment: @АлександрСычёв а так?))

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться `grid` и получить желаемый результат.

```css
.grid
{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr; 
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 10px;
}

.grid__item
{
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 50px;
}

.grid__item:nth-child(1)
{
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
}
.grid__item:nth-child(2)
{
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: 5 / 6;
}

.grid__item:nth-child(3)
{
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
}
.grid__item:nth-child(4)
{
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
}
.grid__item:nth-child(5)
{
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  grid-column: 4 / 5;
}


.grid__item:nth-child(6)
{
  grid-row: 3 / 4;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
}
.grid__item:nth-child(7)
{
  grid-row: 3 / 4;
  grid-column: 5 / 6;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__item">1</div>
  <div class="grid__item">2</div>
  
  <div class="grid__item">3</div>
  <div class="grid__item">4</div>
  <div class="grid__item">5</div>
  
  <div class="grid__item">6</div>
  <div class="grid__item">7</div>
</div>
```

(Подскажите, если это можно как-то сделать подобное grid-template-areas без указание area.)